# How to minimise time for any operation in janusgraph using gremlin?

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, graph-databases, janusgraph, gremlin-server

For any query, it is taking more than five minutes to give result.
I am running simple query  like as following

```
g.V().hasLabel("Label").has("pProperty","vValue").next()
```

When I have lesser number of nodes  it was working fine but now I have more than 1 million nodes, so the issue arises.

Comment: Have you created an index to support queries on that property?

Comment: Glad that was it. I’ll add an answers in case others have the same question.

Answer (score 3):

When using JanusGraph and a Gremlin query to search for a property, if no index has been created for that property the query becomes a full scan over the data. Simple and composite indices can be created using the JanusGraph Management API.  The Gremlin `profile()` step will show you if your query used an index.

Answer (score 1):

Seconding what Kelvin said about adding an index.  To make things more-efficient, you'll either need to filter on additional indexed properties, or make sure that you're designating an appropriate "entry point" for your traversal.